# Current route pattern

Tags: routes, symfony

I'm trying to get the current route pattern in my action, as you can get in the `debug:router` command.

```
all_medias      GET       ANY      ANY    /api/media/all.{_format}
```

I've looked in the `RouterDebugCommand`, but you need an `$input` and `$ouput` object to use the helper. That seems a bit overcomplicated for the task. Is there a way to get a route pattern from a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get route by name from RouteCollection

```
$currentRouteName = $request->attributes->get('_route');
$currentRoutePath = $this->get('router')->getRouteCollection()->get($currentRouteName)->getPath();
```

Or you could also check for its pattern (deprated since 2.2):

```
$currentRoutePattern = $this->get('router')->getRouteCollection()->get($currentRouteName)->getPattern();
```